# MongoDB update multiple array items

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a document with this structure:

```
{
  codeId: 1,
  generatedCodes: [
    {
      name: 'Code 1',
      status: 'In Progress'
    },
    {
      name: 'Code 2',
      status: 'In Progress'
    },
    {
      name: 'Code 3',
      status: 'In Progress'
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to update the `status` property of each object by using the following code:

```
db.codes.update({codeId: id}, {$set: {'generatedCodes.$[].status': 'Validated'}}, {multi: true})
```

But none of the array items get the new `status`...

Comment: Your syntax is correct. It works on my server too

Comment: see the console for your `id`

Comment: The `id` is correct ... there must be something else I'm missing

Comment: can you look at the mongo logs and see the exact query that is executed?

Comment: Run this command in mongo shell `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } ).`

Answer (score 1):

i just run the following and it worked:

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').update({codeId: 1}, {$set: {'generatedCodes.$[].status': 'Validated'}}, {multi: true})
```

the only difference from your code is that i changed {codeId: id} to {codeId: 1}

 so make sure you are passing the correct id.

Comment: And it updated all the `status` property for all objects?

Comment: yes. `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6bfdb818f454e0492896f1"),
    "codeId" : 1,
    "generatedCodes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Code 1",
            "status" : "Validated"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Code 2",
            "status" : "Validated"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Code 3",
            "status" : "Validated"
        }
    ]
}`